# Does Cognito Forms send me an email when someone completes a form?

Tags: cognito-forms

If so, please tell me how to set this up because it it not working.

Answer (score 1):

> Create custom email notifications to get notified when new entries are
>   submitted. Personalize these emails by editing the subject, writing
>   the message, and including options like entry details, payment
>   information, uploaded files, and document copies of entries.

**you should read this it might help -**

https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/20/building-forms/notification-emails